# Need help to write a frequent query in Laravel 3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-3, query-builder

I need a little help writing frequent query in Laravel 3.

I have a table called "votes" which stores user votes in "posts".

so, "votes" table has a "user_id", "post_id" and "timestamp".

Now I need to write a query to show "trending" posts (in a certain timeframe). My logic is to first select records that were added in the desired timeframe (say last 30 days for example), then group the records by post_id and then order them by count.

I can write query for each criteria separately.. but I cant figure out how to incorporate all these criteria in a single query.

Basically... I just want someone to write a frequent query for this SQL

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(*)
FROM votes
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Any kind of help will be immensely appreciated.

Thank You. :)

Comment: What query do you have so far? Also, you might have luck if you ask this with the `mysql` tag as it's not necessarily specific to Laravel.

Comment: @fideloper I have edited my question. Please check!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By frequent query builder, I assume you are referring to Fluent Query Builder.

Using Fluent Query Builder you would have something like this:

Laravel 3:

```
$results = DB::table('votes')->get(array('post_id','count(*)'))->group_by('post_id')->order_by('count(*)','desc')->get();
```

Laravel 4:

```
$results = DB::table('votes')->select('post_id','count(*)')->groupBy('post_id')->orderBy('count(*)','desc')->get();
```

Hope this helps! Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

and i apologize for the stupid mistake. I didnt even realize I was writing frequent. :D

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this.

```
SELECT 
p.post_id, COUNT(*)
FROM 
posts p
LEFT JOIN
votes v
WHERE p.add_date_time > DATE_SUB( CURRENT_DATE() , INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY p.post_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Yes. My query looks something exactly like this. But I need to write this is frequent query builder. Can you help me?

Comment: What do u mean by "frequent query builder" ?